# error in simulating sample.py on gem5: "AttributeError: Not allowed to set pio on 'SimObjectVector' "

Tags: gem5

I have been trying to simulate the 'simple.py' code on gem5 from the gem5 tutorial. Link of the tutorial is: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~david/courses/cs752/Spring2015/gem5-tutorial/part1/simple_config.html#simple-config-fig

I am getting an error saying that "AttributeError: Not allowed to set pio on 'SimObjectVector'".

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: Hi Md, welcome to SO. Questions will be better received here if you include all relevant details in the question instead of providing just an external link. In this case, I recommend that you provide: the python script, the gem5 CLI and the gem5 git revision at least.

Comment: Yes you are right. But i figured it out. Actually i was looking at some older links. Finally i got the new one where the given example is working with the current version of gem5 files. Here is the new link: http://learning.gem5.org/book/part1/simple_config.html.

Answer (score 0):

for this you are getting the error due to the confusion in the ISA architecture and the binary architecture..

```
isa = str(m5.defines.buildEnv['KVM_ISA']).lower()
if isa == "x86" and  m5.defines.buildEnv['USE_ARM_ISA']==False:
    system.cpu.interrupts[0].pio = system.membus.mem_side_ports
    system.cpu.interrupts[0].int_requestor = system.membus.cpu_side_ports
    system.cpu.interrupts[0].int_responder = system.membus.mem_side_ports
```

if your ISA is not an x86 you cant use the pio interrupt  #gem5